# how to destroy all the child elements of a relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_items

class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
```

I want to select all lists of a certain type and then delete all the associated list_items. I've tried map and some other things but stuck.

```
List.where('list_type_id=4').?
```

I know this should be a one-liner but ?

thx

** edit #1**

```
SyntaxError: (irb):94: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'
...ListItem.where('list_id = ?' List.where('list_type_id=4').id)....
...                               ^
(irb):94: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end
...ist.where('list_type_id=4').id).destroy_all
...                               ^
```

Comment: Maybe something like `List.where('list_type_id=4').map(&:list_items).flatten.destroy_all`?

Comment: this looks closest but I get this error msg: `NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy_all' for #<Array:0x007fcb4e63a530>`; really aggrevating; thx

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  Well you can replace the `destroy_all` with an `each {|li| li.delete }`.

Comment: I think this is closet but I still think there's a more railsian way. Thx. `List.where('list_type_id=4').map(&:list_items).flatten.each {|li| li.delete }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity,

```
List.where('list_type_id=4').map(&:list_items).flatten.each {|li| li.delete }
```

but yeah, feels like there should be a Railsier way to do it.

Comment: No , @Joey Hoang answer is more appropriate

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to delete the list, as well as all associated items

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_items, :dependent => :destroy
```

This will set the association to automatically destroy all list_items when the list is deleted.

```
List.where('list_type_id=4').destroy
```

If you want to just delete the ListItems associated with that list

```
ListItem.where('list_id = ?', List.find_by_list_type_id(4).id).destroy_all
```

or

```
List.find_by_list_type_id(4).list_items.destroy_all
```

Comment: Sorry missing comma `ListItem.where('list_id = ?', List.where('list_type_id=4').id).destroy_all`

Comment: seems like it should work but `undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fcb4d6ec7b8> ; it's like it needs to know that that is an array and that it needs to do an in. Like ListItem.where('list_id in ?', List.where('list_type_id=4').id).destroy_all ... but still same error regarding the id; thx
`

Comment: yeah you're right. List.where returns an array so you can do `ListItem.where('list_id = ?', List.find_by_list_type_id(4).id).destroy_all`

Comment: so I think with your strategy, it has to be like this: `ListItem.where('list_id in (?)', List.select('id').where('list_type_id=4')).destroy_all` but I really think there should be a way to get at it from the other side. Kinda like just taking away one of the relationships

Comment: you can also do `List.find_by_list_type_id(4).list_items.destroy_all`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_items, :dependent => :delete_all

List.where('list_type_id=4').list_items.clear
```

Comment: I want to just delete the associated items no the lists and associated items